# How to reverse Engineer a Struct in IDA Pro?

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, malware, dynamic-analysis

How to identify and define a struct in IDA pro Decompiling during reverse engineering?
Please explain the easiest way to figure out the struct in IDA Pro decompilation!
**To make life easier are there any IDA Pro scripts to automate this task?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How-to

To define a valuable structure you need to find its length and memory layout first. If you're researching a C++ binary, this is easiest done by finding the constructor(s) of the structure or its parent and then following all usage of the data across the binary.

### Static analysis

To define a new structure type, open `Local Types` or `Structures` view and press `Insert` to add the structure definition.

You can also create them from pseudocode view by right-clicking the desired variable name and choosing `Create new struct type` or apply an existing type with `Convert to struct *`.

This could be automated using [ida_struct](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_struct.html) and/or [ida_typeinf](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_typeinf.html) modules.

### Debugging

I don't think IDA has any utilities to help you identify or create structures at runtime, but there exist 3rd party tools such as [ReClassEx](https://github.com/ajkhoury/ReClassEx) designed to help with raw memory dump structuring if you need it.